# Do I need a visa to transit through Germany?

Tags: visas, europe, transit, germany, moroccan-citizens

I'm not a citizen and I'm having a flight from Victoria to Vancouver, Vancouver Frankfurt, Frankfurt  Casablanca with Orbitz, but yesterday I received an e-mail from them that said "the destination of the flight was changed and is going to be Victoria Vancouver, Vancouver Berlin (no change airline), Berlin Frankfurt, Frankfurt Casablanca."

So now I don't know if I'm going to need a transit visa because I'm having two stops in Germany, do I?

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you are a Moroccan citizen?

Comment: thank you esultanik,yes im moroccan citizen and im a immegrante permanente in canada,please do you have any information if i need visa transit for too stops in germany? even in berlin no change airplane?

Comment: Berlin->Frankfurt flight within Schengen, thus most likely you'd have to enter Schengen part of the airport. Which AFAIK requires transfer visa.

Answer (score 5):

Given that you are flying into and out of Berlin with the same airline I would strongly recommend you ask them if a visa will be required. Not only is this likely to get you the best/correct answer, it will reduce any issues with them checking your visa when boarding in Canada if one is required.

There are two airports in Berlin (plus a third being built to replace the first two!), but I presume you're referring to Berlin Tegel (TXL).

Tegel has a number of terminals which are configured differently, with terminals A and C being the main terminals for international flights.

Terminal A, instead of having a single passport control/customs area as most airports have, has individual passport control/customs at each gate.  As a result, it's impossible to get from one gate to another "airside", and thus you will need to pass though passport control regardless of where you are connecting to - and for that you will need a Visa.

Terminal C is a more typical layout, with a transit area available for most connecting passengers which does not require passing through passport control.  Passport holders for many (but not all) countries are able to pass through this transit area without obtaining a visa, and that includes citizens of Morocco.

So in short, if your airline uses Terminal A you will need a visa.  If your airline uses Terminal C, you likely will not. But regardless - check with the airline to find out their recommendations and go with what they say.

Answer (score 5):

The route Berlin->Frankfurt is a domestic route. You will need to go through passport control to board a domestic flight. Therefor you **will** need a visa to enter Germany if you are not a national of a country with a visa waiver program with Germany.

You can contact the airline to confirm this but all they are likely to do is direct you towards the nearest German consulate or embassy.

If you are unable to secure a visa (perhaps this being short notice) the airline may be able to reroute you (possibly on a different date). As they have already amended your itinerary from the one you purchased it would not be unreasonable to expect this to be done at no cost to you.