# Require Airport Transit Visa in Germany?

Tags: india, germany, transit, united-airlines, lufthansa

Me and my family is travelling from San Jose, Costa Rica to New Delhi (India) via following itinerary

San Jose (United Airlines) - Houston (United Airlines) - Frankfurt (Lufthansa) - New Delhi

We have 2 hrs transit at Frankfurt and we have a valid B1/B2 U.S. Visa. I called up German Embassy in San Jose and they said that you require a Airport Transit Visa but seeing in various forums and online on German embassy's website I see that though transit is required for Indian Citizens but an exception is there if you have a valid U.S. visa. I am not sure what type of U.S. Visa are they talking about here. Does my B1/B2 visa hold as an exception for transit in that rule?

I am not sure if I need to get the transit visas or not and feel that embassy guys just didn't listen to me properly before giving me a verdict of getting a Transit Visa.

Comment: @Karlson Not at all, the other itinerary includes a flight between two Schengen countries, a completely different situation. But the link in your answer to the other question is relevant and we also have many other related questions.

Comment: @Annoyed Please read the answer.  I linked just one of at least 3 questions on transitting through Frankfurt.

Comment: Related and Duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/transit-visa-travelling-from-canada-to-india-via-germany?rq=1, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14598/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-germany?rq=1,  http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18592/turkish-citizen-us-green-card-holder-but-living-in-uk-germany-transit-visa?rq=1,

Comment: @Karlson Well, I guess I should write “please read my comment”, then. As I said (1) your answer does address this question as well (2) we have many related question but (3) the particular question you linked is very different (i.e. not a duplicate).

Comment: Thank you friends for answering my question. I wrote to German Consulate in Delhi and eventually they replied back that I don't need a Visa. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/20896/2981) applies:

> **No**, you do not need a visa for going from the US to India via
>   Frankfurt airport (or vice versa), as long as you stay in the transit
>   area and have a connection in less than 12 hours. [Lufthansa](http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/in/local?nodeid=3116855&l=en),
>   emphasis mine:
>
> > Indian nationals can Transit without Visa via FRA or MUC if holding a
> >     valid visa for the destination and a valid Visa for any of the
> >     following countries: Bulgaria, Canada, Cyprus, Ireland, Japan,
> >     Liechtenstein, Romania, UK and USA (the approval notice I-797 is not
> >     valid document for visa free airport transit).
>
> [The
>   site of the German Consulate in Kolkata](http://www.india.diplo.de/contentblob/3174898/Daten/3387373/download_datei_transit_visa.pdf) confirms this as well.