# Do I need a transit visa despite having a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, stopovers

I am an Indian citizen living in the US. I am going back to India to get a H1B visa stamped. I have established that I would require an airport transit visa when I have a stopover in Germany.
On the way to India, I plan to visit a friend in Switzerland for a couple of days. For this, I will be applying for a Schengen tourist visa. My itinerary stops in Frankfurt both on the way to Zurich, Switzerland.
Would I still require an airport transit visa despite having a Schengen visa?

Comment: You actually don't need a transit visa in either case: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21957/require-airport-transit-visa-in-germany?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

No, you will simply enter and leave the Schengen area in Frankfurt with your Schengen visa. On the way back from India, you could run into problems because your Schengen visa would presumably not be valid anymore but you will have a valid US visa by that time so you won't need an airport transit visa either.