# Do I need an airport transit visa for layover in Germany?

Tags: visas, air-travel, germany, indian-citizens, romania

I hold an Indian passport.  I'm travelling to Romania with a valid visa.
I have a 5 hour layover at Munich international airport and 3 hour layover at Frankfurt international airport on the way back from Romania.  All the flights are of the same airline.
Everywhere on the internet it says I need an airport transit visa.

However I met a person who said he didn't get a transit visa and still successfully went to Romania and back.

Comment: Lufthansa has an interesting [page with examples](http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/in/local?nodeid=3116855). Hope that helps. [VFS Germany says](http://www.vfs-germany.co.in/Chennai_SouthIndia/faq.html) "NO, you don't need an airport transit visa if you are travelling to US or Canada via Germany and have a valid Visa for the same. However, if you are travelling to any other country you will need to apply for a Transit Visa."

Comment: There are exceptions for visa requirements based on other visas and residence permits.  Do you have any?

Comment: Related questions: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/is-a-schengen-visa-transit-visa-required-for-transit-flight-from-vienna-to-frank, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19137/do-i-need-an-airport-transit-visa-through-switzerland-schengen-if-i-have-no-sc, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14598/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-germany?rq=1, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18592/turkish-citizen-us-green-card-holder-but-living-in-uk-germany-transit-visa?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Indian citizens generally do require a visa in Germany, even for a short transit in an international airport. However, the Romanian visa exempts you from the airport transit visa requirement if you can transit without leaving the transit area of the airport (which is almost certainly your case).

Many web pages only mention valid US visas in this context but the rules are *exactly* the same for Romanian visas. The answer to the following earlier questions therefore also apply: [Do I need a transit visa in Frankfurt, Germany on the way to India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27491/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-in-frankfurt-germany-on-the-way-to-india/27492) and [Do I require airport transit visa at Frankfurt?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23696/do-i-require-airport-transit-visa-at-frankfurt?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Indian nationals can Transit without Visa via FRA or MUC if holding a valid visa for the destination and a valid Visa for any of the following countries:

Bulgaria, Canada, Cyprus, Ireland, Japan, Liechtenstein, Romania, UK and USA (the approval notice I-797 is not valid document for visa free airport transit).

via Lufthansa (http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/in/local?nodeid=3116855)